# Proof of factor.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

If $m$ and $n$ are two positive integers, prove that $x+5$ is the factor for $(x+b)^{n} + (x+4)^{2m+1}$

How to write a proof on this ?

Comment: What is $b$?  The original question had $6$, but it is not true for other numbers.  Take $b=1, x=1, m=0, n=1$ and you are asking that $6$ be a factor of $7$

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), all we fact need to do is show that if $f(x)=(x+6)^{n} + (x+4)^{2m+1}$, then $f(-5)=0$.

Now $f(-5)= (-5+6)^{n} + (-5+4)^{2m+1} = 1^n + (-1)^{2m+1}.$

Since $2m+1$ is odd for all integers $m$, $1^n + (-1)^{2m+1} = 1+ (-1) = 0$

So $f(-5)=0$.

Comment: Sorry. I've typo in my question. I've edited the post

Comment: Are you sure the $b$ isn't actually a 6? Or are there other restrictions on $b$? As Ross pointed out, it isn't true if $b$ is just any integer.

Comment: The question in book states it's 6. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use $((x+5)+1)^n = 1 \pmod{x+5}$, and the other one to have : $1 + (x+4)^{\text{odd}}= (x+5)(...)$